# Transparent background, opaque elements

Tags: html, css, background, opacity

I want to have an image background on `body` and a semitransparent background on main `div`, so that the image can be seen through it, but shaded. However, the easiest

```
body {
  background-image: ...
}

#main {
  background-color: #999;
  opacity: 0.9
}
```

will also make everything within `#main` to be opaque as well, such as any contained `img`.

How do you do what I describe?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rgba helps you, but it is not supported by all browsers

usage:

```
rgba(a,b,c,d), where a = red(0-255); b = green(0-255); c = blue(0-255), d = alpha opacity(0-1)
```

so if you want a 50% red background, you should use

> background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);

Comment: This is the cleanest answer.  For compatibility with some older browsers, a semitransparent png is a good fallback.

Comment: semitransparent pngs have troubles with old IE versions... but even this problem can be solved

Comment: Of course! /doh I don't much care for older browsers, for all I care they can get the monochrome background. Which leads me to my next question: if I write `color: #fee; color: rgba(240, 240, 255, 0.5)`, does it do what I think it does? (i.e. IE6 gets monochrome `#fee`, Chrome understands the `rgba` override? I don't have IE6 to test :)

Comment: yes, Amadan, any version of Google Chrome supports rgba(), here is the refference: http://css-tricks.com/examples/RGBaSupport/

Comment: minor thing but it should read "c = blue(0-255)", it currently reads "b = blue".

Answer (score 3):

If you can use CSS3 for your project you can use rgba()

```
#main {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}
```

The syntax is rgba(Red, Green, Blue, Alpha). This will make the background of #main transparent but not the content.

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neilheinrich/FwxRX/

Answer (score 1):

If you create a semi transparent png file a couple of pixels large and in the colour you are after then add that as the background image of main you should get the desired result.